# Specifying schedule (start date, finish date) for tasks in CMMI process Azure DevOps boards

Tags: azure-devops

I have set up a project in Azure DevOps, selecting the CMMI process as setting (mainly to be able to schedule the start and end dates of each work item).
However, for tasks, I am not able to select neither "Start Date" nor "Finish Date" - both appear with a lock button. I am able, however, to set up both dates for higher level work items such as Features and Epics.
I have tried with both Stakeholder and Basic access, does not work for either of them.
Is there any way on how to configure this? I have not issue with converting from CMMI to another type of project.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start Date** and **Finish Date** fields are calculated if you create a project plan in Microsoft Project and then synchronize that plan with tasks that are stored in Azure Boards. These fields may not appear on the work item form, but they are calculated for those backlog items and tasks that are linked to backlog items. The values are read-only in backlog items and tasks, so you can not modify them.

If you want to set "Start Date" and "Finish Date" for a task, you could customize (need to use inherited process) two Date/Time fields, and add them in a group.

1. Go to inherited process, select Task work item, and hide the "Start Date" and "Finish Date" field:

[image]

2. Create two customized Date/Time fields:

[image]

3. Now you would be able to set Date/Time in Task work item:

[image]

Comment: There is a problem. These new fields does NOT appear en "Delivery Plans". I have tried to create a rule to copy the values to the original Start and Finish dates and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The default Start and Finish date fields in Task Work-Item type can be edited in Backlog view and then using 3 dots (...) option for one or multiple tasks. It opens up a pop-up to select the fields to edit, choose the Start and Finish date fields and set the desired date(s).

click on 3 dots from Backlog view:
[image: click on 3 dots from Backlog view]

select the Start and End date fields in the Pop-up window, choose the desired dates and click save button:
[image: select the Start and End date fields in the Pop-up window, choose the desired dates and click save button]

The updated date fields can be seen by adding the respective columns in the backlog view:
[image: The updated date fields can be seen by adding the respective columns in the backlog view]